# Magento how to create an additional header and reference it in a new template

Tags: php, magento, templates, layout

I am working in magento and have created a new template/layout for the checkout pages. This is very simple header and footer. I obviously still want me standard header and footer for additional pages. Is there a way I can create a new seperate header file and reference it in a new template? Any help on this would be gratefully appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can definitely do this in Magento.

Create new header template and place it under, lets say: `page/html/checkout-header.phtml`.

All you have to do to use this header template on checkout page is add following layout update to your theme's `local.xml`

```
<checkout_onepage_index>
    <reference name="header">
        <action method="setTemplate"><value>page/html/checkout-header.phtml</value></action>
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_index>
```

To change footer template, simply reference `footer` instead of `header`. In case you'd like to update header or footer templates on some other page than checkout, simply change `checkout_onepage_index` to coorect layout handle for that page (`checkout_cart_index` for cart, for example).

Best of luck,

Comment: Hey, thanks very much for taking the time to reply to this. Exactly what I was looking for. thanks again

Comment: Glad I could help. :)